# Open application my screen lose configuration

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a clean installation of ubuntu 22.04 on an HP 650 G1 laptop and whenever I open an application my screen loses its configuration. I have 2 screens connected, one by VGA and one by HDMI
In the image I show is what happens whenever the application is opened and I can't get around it. can you help?

Application example:

- Settings
- Google Chrome
- Mailspring
- Spotify

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJE6V.jpg)

Comment: Sorry I do not see what you are talking about in that screen image. From your question "screen loses its configuration" what does this mean?

Comment: What it means is that when I open an application, the configuration change symbol (As shown in the image) appears and the screens lose their configuration, such as the position, sometimes one of the screens is turned off and I have to go to settings and turn on

Comment: Screen selection feature. The computer is thinking that there has been a physical change to the monitors connected. Now the question is to why.

Comment: That's right, sorry I don't know how to express it better, could it be a problem with drivers?

Comment: Well it appears the monitor or monitors are losing the signal and then getting it back again. Are you using the correct drive for the video?

Comment: yes, I think so but can you help me to find out